# What happens to Firefox Bookmark Tags on export?

Tags: firefox

In contrast to Chrome or Chromium, Firefox uses [Bookmark Tags](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/categorizing-bookmarks-make-them-easy-to-find?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Bookmark+Tags).

- What happens to those tags on export of my bookmarks?
- How are they handled on import into other browsers, e.g. Chrome or Chromium?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What happens to those tags on export of my bookmarks?

They are exported. (Tested with Firefox 48)

> How are they handled on import into other browsers, e.g. Chrome or Chromium?

They are not supported in Chromium (see: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=17536)

Comment: Thank you for investigating! What a pity that these tags are not cross-browser compatible.

Comment: The best thing to do is still to test it by yourself. Exports are just text files, so you can using text-search or grep to see if they contain the desired tags, and then try to import in other browser.

Answer (score 3):

Firefox will export bookmark tags along the record for the bookmarks itself:

```
<DT><A HREF="a url" ADD_DATE="1234" LAST_MODIFIED="1234" TAGS="my,tags">A bookmark</A>
```

These tags may be used by any browser that reads and acknowledges that these tags exist. For example, Chrome currently does not, but Firefox does. This depends on your specific browser, and will likely require testing. Note, that, however, it's not impossible to move tags over. [Open source projects](https://github.com/datamaan/fox2chrome-tags) that will convert between Firefox format and Chrome-aware format do exist, and can be used for this purpose.